# Save progress and submit button for a form

Tags: javascript, php, html, cakephp

I have a form, where most fields are required. Once the form is submitted series of automated tasks gets initiated.

I want to provide users the ability to save their progress and come back and complete the form.

Cookies isn't a option, as users will be logged in to their account and should be able to continue their application from different devices.

The application is saved in the database. I need to do it in a way so that **submit button** submits the form, checks for all the required fields. (It does this currently).

I also need to have a **save progress button** which will ignore the validation and just save the data currently filled. ( No automated tasks etc should run when form is saved using this button.).

Is there a way to achieve this? If so how do i go about it?

The solution above may not be the right / most effective solution. I'm open to any other suggestion.

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

On the second button you can use the `formaction` attribute.

Please note this works only on for buttons with `type="submit"`. Then you can send the save progress info to a different page then just store the info.

```
<button type="submit" formaction="saveprogress.php">Save Progress</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are having two submit buttons, 1. **Submit** and 2. **Save Progress**, then it will be very easy.

Add onClick action on Submit button to validate the form, and after complete validation(return true for correct validation) you can save the data in database.

And on Save progress, just on click of button, you can directly save the data into database.

You need to make the changes in database schema. Add one more column(is_validated), to specify whether the data is validated or not for the user(As mentioned by you, you are firstly logging in user in your application).

When you are fetching data again, you can show the form according to is_validated flag.

Comment: Thanks will give it a go!